# Liferay custom field validation in admin web content

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have added custom fields in admin web content from control panel in liferay 6.1.

Now I am trying to make those fields mandatory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Custom fields are by-design optional in Liferay.

Another solution to your problem could be to use **structured web content** and to define your custom fields as structure fields. In Liferay 6.1, structured fields have several new options, such as marking them as **required**.

E.g. suppose you want to add "Source" information to each web content, then create a new web content structure with the following XSD:

```xml
<root>
    <!-- other fields... -->
    <dynamic-element name='source' type='text' repeatable='false'>
        <meta-data>
            <entry name="displayAsTooltip"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="required"><![CDATA[true]]></entry>
            <entry name="instructions"><![CDATA[News agency this article is coming from]]></entry>
            <entry name="label"><![CDATA[Source]]></entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue"><![CDATA[]]></entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

If you create new articles based on this structure, the content editor must enter a Source for the article or else Liferay will show an error message.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But how I get that custom field value.

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve this value? In Java code or inside a Velocity template?

Comment: Yeah in java code because it store data in journal article table as xml format.should i parse the xml?